# Codeigniter SQLite Insert not recorded

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlite

I am trying to insert records into a DB using CodeIginter and SQLite3, however I am unable to insert them, only to select from database.

I have 777 on the db folder, which includes my test.db file, also using adminer I am able to insert and view records.

This is my method of inserting an array into db:

```
function insertIntoLP($data){
    $this->load->database();
    return $this->db->insert('landing_pages', $data);
}
```

The code which is calling the above method is:

```
$data = array(
            'id'    => '',
            'brand' => $brand,
            'name' => $name,
            'settings' => serialize($settings),
            'date' => time(),
        );

        return $this->dbsql->insertIntoLP($data);
```

It's returning success but the records are not recorded. Any ideas?

Comment: If you can select, but not insert, double check the DB user you've connected as has INSERT permissions.

Comment: I have permission to insert. I am using adminer to insert and it works.

Comment: I have managed to get a more detailed error "Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /var/www/sites/www.traffic.dev/www/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php on line 193" but I don't know what does it means exactly

Comment: Check in your configuration file if php_pdo_sqlite is enabled.

Comment: My phpinfo() returns this : 
"SQLite3 module version 0.7-dev
SQLite Library 3.6.20
sqlite3.extension_dir" as enabled

Comment: Also the above error is displayed only on insert, however the select works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of CodeIgniter you are using.
But, between the version 2.1.4 and 2.2.0 someone noticed that the file `system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php"` change.

In the current version 2.2.0 an [issue has been open  and a fix](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/3095) has been given. Maybe you should take a look and **keep up-to-date your application**.

Your code is correct and you have installed drivers, so I hope it will solve your problem.

---

### After your edition:

Table architecture still missing but I guess your array of `$data` should be like this:

```
$data = array(
        'brand' => $brand,
        'name' => $name,
        'settings' => serialize($settings),
        'date' => time(),
);
```

I've remove the id. If it's defined as auto increment in your database, just remove it from your request.

**You was doing:**

`INSERT INTO landing_pages(id, brand, name, settings, date) VALUES (NULL, 'Some Data', 'Some Data', 'Some Data', 'Date')`

**But it should work better without id:**

`INSERT INTO landing_pages(brand, name, settings, date) VALUES ('Some Data', 'Some Data', 'Some Data', 'Date')`

Comment: found the error issue, I was passing the wrong parameters. However still not inserting into DB

Comment: I have no error displaying, the insert is a success but, when I am check the database, nothing inside

Comment: Can you provide more code in your question please. (`$data` value and maybe database architecture).

Comment: Yes, you are write, removing the ID from the $data solved the problem. Thank you